# How to disable JPA auditing for a specific action

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, auditing

In have a Spring web application with JPA auditing enabled:

```
<jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="auditorAware"/>
```

Inside all entities I use all 4 auditing annotations:

```
@LastModifiedBy
@LastModifiedDate
@CreatedBy
@CreatedDate
```

Now for a specific controller method, e.g. `BatchImportController.import()` that does some batch operations on entities , I would like to disable entity auditing. Is this possible?